# How to parse Net.WebClient results with VB.net

Tags: vb.net, webclient

```
Using client As New Net.WebClient
    Dim reqparm As New Specialized.NameValueCollection
    'reqparm.Add("param1", "somevalue")
    'reqparm.Add("param2", "othervalue")
    Dim responsebytes = client.UploadValues("http://ip2country.sourceforge.net/ip2c.php?format=JSON", "POST", reqparm)
    Dim responsebody = (New Text.UTF8Encoding).GetString(responsebytes)

End Using
```

Results in:

> {ip: "184.23.135.130",hostname:
>   "184-23-135-130.dedicated.static.sonic.net",country_code:
>   "US",country_name: "United States"}

Looking for any help

Comment: The result is a JSON string. You can any one of a number of JSON libraries to read it. JSON.NET, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I included Json.net references.

```
 Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq
 Imports System.Net

 Using client As New Net.WebClient
        Dim reqparm As New Specialized.NameValueCollection
        'reqparm.Add("param1", "somevalue")
        'reqparm.Add("param2", "othervalue")
        Dim responsebytes = client.UploadValues("http://ip2country.sourceforge.net/ip2c.php?format=JSON", "POST", reqparm)
        Dim responsebody = (New Text.UTF8Encoding).GetString(responsebytes)
        Dim blah As String = client.DownloadString("http://ip2country.sourceforge.net/ip2c.php?format=JSON")
        Dim json As JObject = JObject.Parse(responsebody)
        Console.WriteLine(json.SelectToken("ip"))
        Console.WriteLine(json.SelectToken("hostname"))
        Console.WriteLine(json.SelectToken("country_code"))
        Console.WriteLine(json.SelectToken("country_name"))
        Console.ReadKey()
 End Using
```